прошу помощи не могу вызвать переменную через basename из другого файла на bash
index.sh
    for INDEX in "$HOME/$SHA/"*
do
  "$INDEX" &  
done 

1file.sh
filename="$INDEX"
basename="$(basename "$filename" .sh)"

команда с названием переменной $basename
bzip2 "$HOME/$FILE/$basename-$FILENUM"


Что такое index.sh и 1file.sh? Окуда должна взяться переменная INDEX в 1file.sh?

что значит откуда, а э что такое ?     for INDEX in "$HOME/$SHA/"*
do
"$INDEX" &
done

Вы запускаете новый скрипт. Он ничего не знает о переменных скрипта из которого его запустили.
